# Adding functionality to an existing class in OOP

Tags: java, c++, oop, opengl

With object oriented programming, we often use polymorphism to make several different types of objects behave under the same 'interface'. The bread and butter example is like so:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void makeSound();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Woof woof");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }
}
```

We don't care what the actual animal is, only that it can make a sound.

However the problem occurs when we want to add a new feature to existing classes.
In my case, I seek to make several classes implement the `UniformProvider` interface (it converts the class to a raw uniform value for an OpenGL shader program).

Up until now I have used a simple `instanceof` check that handles a number of possible types, however I don't want to rely on `instanceof` as it is not easily extensible without modifying the source file.

The problem with the `UniformProvider` interface is that it cannot be implemented for built in types like `float` (or `Float`), `int` (or `Integer`), and arrays of objects (eg: `Matrix4f[]`). Furthemore, I believe putting the functionality for uniform variable conversion into mathematics classes violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

In the Rust language, structs have a useful feature that I've now just realised the potential of. In traditional OOP, the class/struct implements the interface/trait, and more interfaces can't be implemented without modifying original file. However in Rust one provides and implementation of a trait *for* a struct, thus reversing the dependency. This uses the syntax like `impl Add for Vector4f` instead of `Vector4f implements Add`.

I am pondering what options exist in traditional OOP languages such as Java or C++ for such a pattern. I considered creating a registry of *converters*, that are assigned to a class: eg `FloatConverter` for `float`, and then accessing the relevant converter using a HashMap or equivalent, but I thought this might be quite inefficient.

I ask what solutions for this dilemma are out there (or if I should just switch to Rust :) [I'm thinking of anyway]).

Comment: What you want is also called typeclasses in Haskell. You can use generics to achieve similar results, see e.g. https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/type-classes/ .

Comment: I think you are looking for [traits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)), which is not implemented in java. It is implemented in Scala, however!

Comment: Yes I think Java can't provide a true solution.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution to this is the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

```
// Base object hierarchy

abstract class Animal {
  abstract void Accept(AnimalVisitor visitor);
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  void Accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
   void Accept(AnimalVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
}

interface AnimalVisitor {
  Visit(Dog dog);
  Visit(Cat cat);
}

// Here is a concrete visitor ...

class AnimalNoiseMaker implements AnimalVisitor {
  Visit(Dog dog) { System.out.println("Woof woof"); }
  Visit(Cat cat) { System.out.println("Meow"); }
}

// .. and how you use it

Animal a = ...;
a.Accept(new AnimalNoiseMaker()); // Woof or Meow !
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still requires that all types to be implemented are listed in one file (the `AnimalVisitor` interface). But it does do a good job at inverting control from the animal itself to another class.

Comment: To my understanding, this is not what the OP is looking for. The visitor pattern requries modifying the class's code, which is NOT what the OP is asking, he wants to ADD functionality to implementing class, without changing the parent class (Imaigine you don't have access to `Animal`, and you need to add functionality to classes that extend it). Furthermore, for the usage you described, the visitor pattern is just an overkill where strategy would do just fine.

Comment: It might not be quite what I was after, but it is still something good to add to my knowledge belt. Please don't get angry at Nicolas, I'm sure he was just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to add behaviour to an existing class when I can't modify the existing:

```
public final class EmpoweredAnimal extends Animal
{
    private final Animal animal;

    public EmpoweredAnimal(Animal animal)
    {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    @Override
    public final void makeSound()
    {
        this.animal.makeSound();
    }

    public final void jump()
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Animal myDog = new Dog();
//Drawback: you must base your polymorphism on the EmpoweredAnimal now
EmpoweredAnimal myEmpoweredDog = new EmpoweredAnimal(myDog);
myEmpoweredDog.makeSound(); //prints "woof woof"
myEmpoweredDog.jump(); //do something new
```

The drawback can be acceptable if all your animals have to be empowered otherwise you're forced to continue using *instanceof* because not all of the `Animal` will be wrapped in an `EmpoweredAnimal`.